# Create Certificate Signing Request (CSR) with Subject Alternative Name (SAN) on Windows without third party tools

Tags: windows, iis, ssl-certificate, certificate-signing-request

I need to create a CSR on Windows with Subject Alternative Names. Normally I use the built in feature from `IIS` but it does not give the alternative to use Subject Alternative Name (SAN).

I know that I can use `DigiCert Certificate Utility` for this but it is not an option to install.

https://www.digicert.com/util/csr-creation-microsoft-servers-using-digicert-utility.htm

Using MMC -> Request new certificate has no enrollment policy.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found the way to do it:

MMC -> Certificates(Local Computer) -> Right click on the Personal folder -> All Tasks -> Advanced Operations -> Create Custom Request...

[image]

I choose `Proceed without enrollment policy` and clicked next. Choose `(No Template) Legacy key` for compatibility and more options and use `PKCS #10`. Click on next and click on `Properties`.

[image]

Enter a Friendly name and Description and hit apply. Don't forget to hit apply after changes has been done on each tab.

Other tab examples for https certificate. Remember to add a valid Host + Domain Name for Common Name (CN), should look like `www.yoursite.com` or `yoursite.com`. Subject Alternative Names should be added under `Alternative name` and Type `DNS`.

If you need a new CSR similar to an existing certificate look at that certificate details and the Fields `Subject` and `Subject Alternative Name`

[image]

Under the tab `Extensions` choose <s>`Client Authentication`</s> `Server Authentication` for `Extended Key Usage (application policies)`.

[image]

Under the tab `Private Key` choose `Key size` 4096 and `Make private key exportable`.

If you have the `Key type` flap choose `Exchange` otherwise check that `Select Hash Algorithm` is set to `sha256`.

[image]

If you choose `(No Template) CNG key` it will look like this:

[image]

Save with OK and then save the file as `Base64`.

Comment: Thank you for posting that!  However, I think the proper choice would be "Server Authentication".  At least that is what I think it should be for a web server SSL cert.

Comment: @JimClark Thanks, I think you are correct. :)

Comment: What file extension to use?

Comment: @user230910 - I don't think it matters. I always use `.csr` and nobody has ever complained.